# Change section key to less-than in OS X

Tags: macos, keyboard-layout, osx-mountain-lion

I'm having trouble getting my keyboard layout to be properly recognized. At the moment everything else is fine, but my less-than key (<kbd><</kbd>) is mapped to the section key (<kbd>§</kbd>), which makes writing HTML a pain. I've tried Ukelele and KeyRemap4MacBook, but can't seem to find the correct settings to change.

For reference, this is my layout: [Finnish Multilingual](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=File:KB_Finnish_Multilingual.svg&page=1), and in System Preferences the input is set to Finnish.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you try saving something like this as [private.xml](http://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/xml.html.en)?

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
<item>
<name>test</name>
<identifier>test</identifier>
<autogen>--KeyToKey-- KeyCode::SWEDISH_SECTION, KeyCode::SWEDISH_LESS_THAN</autogen>
<autogen>--KeyToKey-- KeyCode::SWEDISH_LESS_THAN, KeyCode::SWEDISH_SECTION</autogen>
</item>
</root>
```

The [key code constants](https://github.com/tekezo/KeyRemap4MacBook/blob/master/src/bridge/generator/keycode/data/KeyCode.data) are defined in the source. The test folder has an [XML file](https://github.com/tekezo/KeyRemap4MacBook/blob/master/Tests/lib/string/data/checkbox.xml?raw=true) with all the predefined remappings.

Comment: I was going around in circles with this for a while. Couldn't find the correct keycodes. This finally solved it, thank you.

Comment: Works nicely, but done like this it also applies to the laptop integrated keyboard. Follow these instructions to only remap on my external keyboard: https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/xml.html.en#devicedef

Answer (score 4):

After upgrading from Lion to Mountain Lion I had the same issue using a Logitech keyboard  and the Spanish ISO layout.

Take a look at your `/Library/Preferences/com.apple.keyboardtype.plist` file using a Property List Editor. It may look something like this:

```
Root
  keyboardtype
    49949-1133-0      43
```

Replacing `43` with a `41` solved the problem for me:

```
Root
  keyboardtype
    49949-1133-0      41
```

Comment: Thank you! Google found this question asked many times on many sites and forums over the years, but this is the only answer that fixes the problem directly and without third party software.

Comment: I deleted `/Library/Preferences/com.apple.keyboardtype.plist` and restarted. I got a "New keyboard detected" dialog box when booting up again. Pressed the key next to the left-shift and it fixed itself.

Answer (score 0):

Running El Capitan 10.11.06, MacBook Pro and using a cheap external Finnish Logitech Windows keyboard, same issue as OP. The instructions above work, but it takes a while to figure it out so here are some time saving tips:

1. Download and install [Karabiner](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/) (former "KeyRemap4MacBook"). Be sure to give it proper [permissions](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/document.html.en) to make changes in OS X.
2. Open Karabiner and open the very first item in the list "Karabiner core settings" and then "Excluded devices". Check whatever devices you don't need to remap <> to § and vice-versa.
3. Click on "Misc & Uninstall" and click "Open private.xml". This should now open private.xml in Finder. This is the file you add the key swap to. Open the file in a text editor.
4. Copy paste this over the current contents of private.xml and save the file (credit to user495470).

`<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
<item>
<name>Less-than swap</name>
<identifier>test</identifier>
<autogen>--KeyToKey-- KeyCode::SWEDISH_SECTION, KeyCode::SWEDISH_LESS_THAN</autogen>
<autogen>--KeyToKey-- KeyCode::SWEDISH_LESS_THAN, KeyCode::SWEDISH_SECTION</autogen>
</item>
</root>`

5. In Karabiner, go to the main menu "Change key" and hit "Reload XML". Check the "Less-than swap" box.
6. Voilà! You're done, enjoy your <> keys!